# input type:submit not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to develop a form that asks a question and has 2 options and finally, an input of type submit using javascript.

HTML :

```html
<div class="intro py-3 bg-white text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-primary display-3 my-4">Ninja Quiz</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=" quiz py-4 bg-primary">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="my-5 text-white">On with questions</h2>

    <form class="quiz-form text-light">
      <div class="my-5">
        <p class="lead font-weight-normal">
          1.How do you give Ninja Directions?
        </p>
        <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
          <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="a" checked />
          <label for="q1" class="form-check-label">Show Them A map</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
          <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="b" />
          <label for="q1" class="form-check-label"
            >Dont worry a ninja will find you</label
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My ts page is :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
const correctAnswers = ['b'];
const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-udemy',
  templateUrl: './udemy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./udemy.component.css'],
})

export class UdemyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  if(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      console.log(form);
      e.preventDefault();
      let score = 0;
      const userAnswers = [form.q1.value];
      userAnswers.forEach((answer, index) => {
        if (answer === correctAnswers[index]) {
          score = 100;
        }
      });
      console.log(score);
    });
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing now is that when I click on submit nothing happens. My requirement is that when I click on submit, the `eventListener` gets triggered and displays the score.

Comment: You closed ngOnInit too early. Check the code bellow: 

ngOnInit(): void {
  if(form){
    form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
      console.log(form);
      e.preventDefault();
      let score=0;
      const userAnswers=[form.q1.value];
      userAnswers.forEach((answer,index)=>
      {
        if(answer===correctAnswers[index]){
          score=100
        }

      })
      console.log(score)

    })
    }
}

Comment: are you suggesting to put the entire code in ngOnIt?

Comment: I suspect you must have loads of errors. You might want to follow some angular tutorials first?

Comment: there are no errors. the code compiled successfully

Comment: It looks not very well, I would suggest you to use angular (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" approach. But if you need to use this code - try to use ngAfterContentInit() method and move `const form = document.querySelector('.quiz-form');` from the top to that method with the rest of your code. But I'm really not sure if it works, because as I said it is not a angular style. but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you sould use form in angular :

in component.html :

```
<form class="quiz-form text-light" 
    #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm)">

     <div class="form-check my-2 text-white-50">
      <input type="text" name="q1" id="q1" [(ngModel)]="q1" />
    </div>
        .....
      <div class="text-center">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light" />
     </div>
</form>
```

in `component.ts` :

```
submitForm(form:any) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
```

Comment: Ithis helps but my requirement is that it should be done using javascript.

Comment: then why are you using  Angular ?

Comment: i am not using angular,just implemented this code as one of the components for my personal work,